# Space after 'if', 'while', 'catch' etc.. with clang-format

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

Cannot figure out that option adds the space after `if`, `while`, `catch`, etc...

Currently my .clang-format file produce this:

```
        while(true)
        {
            if(flushedCount == count)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

The `clang-format` configuration option controlling space after `if`, `while`, `catch` and other control statements is called `SpaceBeforeParens`.

```
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
```

From [clang-format 8 documentation](http://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> **SpaceBeforeParens** (`SpaceBeforeParensOptions`)
>
> Defines in which cases to put a space before opening parentheses.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - *[...]*
> - `SBPO_ControlStatements` (in configuration: `ControlStatements`) Put a space before opening parentheses only after control statement keywords (`for/if/while...`).
> - *[...]*

Comment: Maybe like me you came here to know if there was a way to add spacing around a control statement *inside* the parentheses. Alas as per Sep 2, 2022, with clang-format 14, `SpaceAfterParens: ControlStatements` does not exist.